# Type inference - could not deduce Monad

Tags: haskell, reflex

I am building a way to display a dialog to users.

```
data DialogConfig t m b e =
  DialogConfig { _dialogConfig_title :: Dynamic t T.Text
               , _dialogConfig_content :: b -> m (Dynamic t (Maybe b))
               , _dialogConfig_footer :: Dynamic t (Maybe b) -> m (Event t e)
               }
dialog :: MonadWidget t m =>
           DialogConfig t m b e -> Event t b -> m (Event t (DialogEvent e))
```

I would like to use some kind of 'default' instance to initialize `DialogConfig` for the `dialog` function, so that I could use it as e.g. `defaultConfig{_dialogConfig_content=content}`. However, I'm fighting with type inferrence. This works:

```
confirmDialog :: forall t m. MonadWidget t m =>
                 T.Text -> Event t T.Text -> m (Event t ())
...
evt <- dialog
         (DialogConfig { _dialogConfig_title = constDyn title
                       , _dialogConfig_content = content
                       , _dialogConfig_footer = buttons}
                       ) contentEvt
```

However, when I use some default `DialogConfig` (e.g. here directly inlining it), it doesn't:

```
evt <- dialog
      (DialogConfig { _dialogConfig_title = constDyn mempty
                    , _dialogConfig_content = const $ return $ constDyn Nothing
                    , _dialogConfig_footer = const $ return never }
                    { _dialogConfig_title = constDyn title
                    , _dialogConfig_content = content
                    , _dialogConfig_footer = buttons}
                    ) contentEvt
```

The errors are:

```
Could not deduce (Reflex t0) arising from a use of ‘constDyn’ from the context (MonadWidget t m)
Could not deduce (Monad t1) arising from a use of ‘return’ from the context (MonadWidget t m)
```

I can use `ScopedTypeVariables` and type the default config in the `confirmDialog` as `DialogConfig t m a b` and that works, however shouldn't it work even without it? It seems to me that the types are rather unambiguous.

Comment: There is a very nice (although still experimental) formulation of modal dialogs in [reflex-dom-contrib](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-dom-contrib/blob/master/src/Reflex/Dom/Contrib/Widgets/Modal.hs)

Comment: We decided for our own implementation for the time being...

Comment: The errors are probably due to the fact that the values in the former record updates are unused, so their types will naturally be ambiguous. The essential problem, it seems, is that record updates can change the type of the record. To get the type inference you want, you'll have to define some way of updating the record (e.g. lenses) in a way that doesn't change the type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that record update can *change* the type of the record (which can be surprising at first). Here's a test in GHCi:

```
> data T a = T { tA :: a }
> let x = T "foo"
> :t x
x :: T [Char]
> :t x { tA = True }
x { tA = True } :: T Bool
```

So, we can't define a default:

```
> let def :: Read a => T a ; def = T (read "True")
> :t def :: T Bool
def :: T Bool :: T Bool
> :t def { tA = 5 }
   Could not deduce (Read t0) arising from a use of ‘def’
   The type variable ‘t0’ is ambiguous
```

Indeed, above `def` could be of any type.

A possible solution could be forcing the update to have the same type by requiring a `T a -> T a` continuation function.

```
> let defF :: Read a => (T a -> T a) -> T a ; defF f = f (T (read "True"))
> :t defF (\d -> d { tA = False })
defF (\d -> d { tA = False }) :: T Bool
```

Above `d` is the default which, by construction, must have the same type of the record after the update.

With lenses, there might be better approaches.

Comment: I will accept this as an answer - yes, the fact that the update can change the type was unexpected although quite logical.